# Use AWS SAM for local AWS Lambda testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, docker-machine, aws-sam-cli

I'm looking to use AWS' SAM to locally develop, test and package scripts before pushing them to AWS Lambda. I'm using Docker Toolbox (17.10.0-ce) with AWS SAM (0.2.2) to run the same code that I have on the actual AWS Lambda itself - and I know it works. My `MyMainFunction.py` is as follows:

```
import json
def l_handle(event, context):
    payload = json.loads(event.get('body'))
    op1 = payload['op1']
    op2 = payload['op2']
    operator = payload['op']
    if op1 == 0 or op2 == 0 or operator == None:
        result = 'Please enter valid input data'
        ret_code = 219
    else:
        if operator in {'add', 'plus', '+'}:
            result = op1 + op2
            ret_code = 278
        elif operator in {'subtract', 'minus', '-'}:
            result = op1 - op2
            ret_code = 278
        elif operator in {'multiply', '*'}:
            result = op1 * op2
            ret_code = 278
        elif operator in {'divide', '/'}:
            result = op1 / op2
            ret_code = 278
        else:
            result = 'Please enter valid operator'
            ret_code = 219
    print(result)
    return {
        'isBase64Encoded': False,
        'statusCode': ret_code,
        'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        'body': json.dumps(result)
    }
```

With the `event.json` being as follows:

```
{
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": null,
    ...
      },
      "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "apiId": "*"
    },
    "body": "{\"op1\":2,\"op2\":7,\"op\":\"divide\"}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
```

and the `template.yaml` being as follows:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
  Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
  Description: A simple Calc application.
  Resources:
    MyMainFunction:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        Handler: l_handle
        Runtime: python3.6
```

When I try and run the command in Docker as `$ sam local invoke MyMainFunction --event event.json`, I get an error, as given below:

```
muham@DESKTOP-BS30EMD MINGW64 ~/Documents/Codes/lambdaLocal
$ sam local invoke MyMainFunction --event event.json
2017/11/25 20:52:57 Successfully parsed template.yaml
[34mINFO[0m[0000] Unable to use system certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows
2017/11/25 20:52:57 Connected to Docker 1.34
[34mINFO[0m[0000] Unable to use system certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows
2017/11/25 20:52:57 Fetching lambci/lambda:python3.6 image for python3.6 runtime...
python3.6: Pulling from lambci/lambda
Digest: sha256:3663b89bd1f4c4d1a4f06a77fc543422c1f0cbfc3a2f491c8c7bdc98cf9cf0b6
Status: Image is up to date for lambci/lambda:python3.6
2017/11/25 20:52:59 Invoking l_handle (python3.6)
2017/11/25 20:53:00 Could not invoke function: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:/Users/muham/Documents/Codes/lambdaLocal:/var/task:ro'
```

This clearly has something to do with the volumes. However, unfortunately, I only started using Dockers about five hours ago (and have been researching volumes and mounts since) so I'm not sure why is Docker appending `:/var/task:ro` at the end of normal directory or how to resolve it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you run sam build before invoke?